# how to add addtional attribute in option in laravel blade ( Laravel 5.6)

Tags: laravel

```
{!! Form::select('gl_code', [''=>'']+$coa->pluck('coa_info','COAID')->toArray(), old('gl_code', isset($data) ? $data->gl_code: 0), ['id'=>'coa_gl','name'=>'gl_code','class'=>'an-form-control','style'=>'width: 150px;']) !!}
```

I want to insert `'data-desc'=>'COADesc'` in option in my dropdown list.

Comment: Try inserting code rather than linking as an image, and please formate your code as code not text

Answer (score -1, accepted):

add the  **'data-desc'=>'COADesc'** in the array.
for more info check this: [Laravel Select](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#drop-down-lists)

```
{!! Form::select('gl_code', [''=>'']+$coa->pluck('coa_info','COAID')->toArray(), old('gl_code', isset($data) ? $data->gl_code: 0), ['id'=>'coa_gl','name'=>'gl_code','class'=>'an-form-control','style'=>'width: 150px;', 'data-desc'=>'COADesc']) !!}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply add it after your style attribute **, 'data-desc'=>'COADesc'**. It is same as any other attribute ( id or name or class).

Hope it helps..cheers.